# What does paying by invoice mean?

Tags: india, online-payment, terminology, ecommerce, billing

I was trying to buy a book from Springer in the Yellow Sale 2012. I chose to pay by invoice, without knowing what it means!?!

Further, if it matters -- I filled in: Billing address, Shipping address and invoice address with the same address, namely mine.

Further, the order summary reads that my mode of payment is: `Billing`

Can you please elaborate to me on what this means?

Answer (score 7):

They are going to email you an invoice, and you are required to pay that like any other bill that comes in.

> 10.6 The Customer shall be billed electronically for the goods and services ordered, and invoices shall be sent to the eMail address he
>   or she has specified. If the Customer also wants paper invoices to be
>   sent, Springer may charge a separate fee for this.

from http://www.springer.com/generic/terms?SGWID=0-40112-0-0-0

My speculation is that they offer these terms because buyers of their products might have to submit a paper bill for reimbursement or submit the invoice to a accounts payable department.  You can use the service and it just delays by a few days when you need to settle up.

They will send you an invoice.  On the bottom there will be a portion to detach and mail back.  They might even include an envelope.  You write a check addressed to the payable name on the invoice and mail it, along with detachable part of the invoice to the address they specify.

Answer (score 1):

Some companies/sites allow customers to pay at a later date by issuing credit terms without charging interest as long as the invoice is paid within a certain time frame. Such kind of payment method is called 'Payment by Invoice' or 'Charge by Invoice'. Please do not forget to read the payment terms in such cases.